# How to determine the cost of a BigQuery query?

Tags: php, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

Recently my BQ bill got higher and higher because of large queries that I'm running for my clients. Now, I want to know how to price each query is using.

So, to do that I need one of the two:

1. how much bytes the query use.
2. price of the query.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
            $bq = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
        $job = new Google_Service_Bigquery_Job();
        $config = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfiguration();
        // $config->setDryRun(false);
        $config->setDryRun(true);
        $queryConfig = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobConfigurationQuery();
        $config->setQuery($queryConfig);
        $job->setConfiguration($config);
        $queryConfig->setQuery($sql);
        try {
            $job = $bq->jobs->insert($project_id , $job);
            $status = new Google_Service_Bigquery_JobStatus();
            $status = $job->getStatus();
            if ($status->count() != 0) {

                $err_res = $status->getErrorResult();
                die($err_res->getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            // echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
        $jr = $job->getJobReference();

        $jobId = $jr['jobId'];
        if ($status)
            $state = $status['state'];
        $res = $bq->jobs->getQueryResults($project_id, $jobId, array('timeoutMs' => 100000));

        if (!$res->jobComplete) {
            exit;
        }
        $rows = $res->getRows();

        $r = new Google_Service_Bigquery_TableRow();
        $a = array();
        foreach ($rows as $r) {
            $r = $r->getF();
            $temp = array();
            foreach ($r as $v) {
                $temp[] = $v->v;
            }
            $a[] = $temp;
        }
        return $a;
```

But, the output is:

```
 - Uncaught Google_Exception: (getQueryResults) missing required param:
   'jobId' in
   /vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service/Resource.php:165
```

for some reason when the dry run is true, it doesnt make a jobid.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to execute the dryrun request and examine the response.  This code appears to simply build a config and print it without execution.

Comment: You should also seriously consider turning on audit logs and examining your query costs that way too. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Comment: @GrahamPolley Polley thanks i now using the audit, but all my clients queries are on my user name , so i cant break it down by each... i edit my question.